# Debug android/ios app sqlite DB

Tags: android, ios, sqlite

I am developing an app for ios and android. I am using sqlite to store some data in phones.

Is it possible to check while debugging what the stored data is? I mean, if I can check that the data I want to store is being stored or not...

I need to do if its possible  and in that case, which tools I need for xcode5 in mac and intellij or android studio in windows.

Comment: For Android you can download [asqlitemanager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanagerd) and [ashell](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.aShell). So you'll see the data stored in the SqLite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use SQLite Database Browser
(http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/)

Just grab a copy of the DB from the device (easy on Android with ADB, on iOS I enable file sharing so I can grab files easily back off device) and load it into the app.

Comment: so I cannot have a connection stabilished with DB in the phone while I am testing can I? I have to copy the db each time I want to check data...

Comment: not that I am aware of on iOS. I just pause on a breakpoint, grab and inspect. It obviously easier if you are on simulator as the file is just sitting on your harddisk

Answer (score 1):

1.)if you are working with eclipse then SQLite plugin available in market, and you can watch it in file ecplorer.

2.) after run your project mins completed your SQLite operation.
   you should pull your db file on desktop from your emulator or device from your application installed "data/data" path and after you checked it on SQLite manager.

NOTE: This operation possible only with the  Emulator or rooted devices.